# Oridomi 2 sided folds (content at the front and back)

Tags: javascript, jquery, oridomi

I'm playing around with Oridomi, but can't find the way to have 2 sided fold. Like image at the front and back (or content). So when it is folded the other opposite content is displayed. Like double sided brochure or greeting card.

Is there a way to implement that with Oridomi or are there any other alternatives?